# Uncaught ReferenceError while calling the function from body

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to solve this problem, although I'm not a js developer and my implementations are pretty lame sometimes.

I defined in external js this function:

```
function moveScroller() {
        var move = function() {
            var st = $(window).scrollTop();
            var ot = $("#scroller-anchor").offset().top;
            var s = $("#scroller");
            if(st > ot) {
                s.css({
                    position: "fixed",
                    top: "60px"
                });
            } else {
                if(st <= ot) {
                    s.css({
                        position: "relative",
                        top: ""
                    });
                }
            }
        };
        $(window).scroll(move);
        move();
    }
```

and than in html in body i have this code:

```
<div style="width:900px; position:relative; margin:0 auto; border:1px solid red; padding-top:300px; padding-left:60px;">
<div id="scroller-anchor"></div>
<div class="info_holder" id="scroller">Information in here and here</div>

random and random<br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
random and random<br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
random and random<br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
random and random<br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
random and random<br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
random and random<br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
random and random<br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
random and random<br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
random and random<br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
random and random<br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
random and random<br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
random and random<br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
random and random<br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
random and random<br /><br /><br /><br /><br />

</div>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
        moveScroller();
    });
</script>
```

I tried the body part of the script execute without $(document).ready but it gives me the same error Uncaught ReferenceError: moveScroller is not defined.

http://jsfiddle.net/A6gYg/76/
or http://atargeta.staging.wpengine.com/modules/ if you open console you should see the only error.

Comment: The JS window in jsFiddle loads depending on what you select in the dropdown on the left, when you set it to `onLoad` the window loads your function when the DOM has loaded, which is later than the DOM ready handler you placed directly in the body. Just place the function in the body somewhere before the code that calls it, preferrably in the same script tag ?

Answer (score 0):

Change your javascript to be placed in the `<head>`. That way it is available once your `$(document).ready();` call happens. The way you have it set up now, the function will be created after you use it. You want it to be created *before* you use it.

[image: No wrap - in <head>]

[It is not a best practice to place javascript in the `<head>`](http://samsaffron.com/archive/2012/02/17/stop-paying-your-jquery-tax), but for the sake of example, placing it in the `<head>` will fix your issue.

Comment: Hey kavun, thanks that worked on that jfiddle. On my website this is difficult to solve it this way because i didn't want to change anything in that customized paid wordpress theme. But I think I'll have to do it this way :)